# Changing the datetime format in a query Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and SQLalchemy, I am currently working on querying a MySql database and using the result in javascript. This is an example of the query below:

```
 month = db.session.query(Certificates.msm, Certificates.certificate_type, func.count(Certificates.id),func.month(Certificates.delivery_time)).filter(Certificates.report_sent).filter(Certificates.msm == msm).group_by(Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.msm, func.month(Certificates.delivery_time)).all()
```

The result looks like this:

```
[('bob', 'base-certificate', 60, 3), ('bob', 'case-certificate', 1, 3), ('bob', 'standard-certificate', 7, 3)]
```

It returns the month as a number for March, in this case 3 which makes it difficult for javascript to understand.
I tried to reformat the query to present a different format: **func.month to func.strftime**

```
month = db.session.query(Certificates.msm, Certificates.certificate_type, func.count(Certificates.id),func.strftime(%m,Certificates.delivery_time)).filter(Certificates.report_sent).filter(Certificates.msm == msm).group_by(Certificates.certificate_type, Certificates.msm, func.month(Certificates.delivery_time)).all()
```

but it gave me an error message that the method does not exist

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1305, 'FUNCTION slowmo.strftime does not exist')
```

is there a way to display a different date format that aggregates a record for the month and display it as a date object not an integer in a format that is readable format  in javascript or easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the python's built-in datetime library. It has some functions to return full date&time objects in different formats based on given numbers.

Comment: Thank you, i will search for such functions, but I am very new to python, any where I can start looking for?

Comment: Just search google for 'python datetime'.
It's official documentation:
[Python Datetime Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)